# PHPmyAdmin Notice and Crash \libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#1190

Tags: phpmyadmin

I added 4 new Columns to my table (which was running perfect) making total columns to 19. When clicking "browse" tab, its as if now that I would have to scroll over to the new columns, it crashes and will not display the new columns.

If I click the "Structure" tab, all columns are present and correct.

I get to PHPmyAdmin through MAMP, or by just typing `localhost/phpmyadmin`

Using:

```
MAMP 
PHP 7.4.1
MySQL Version 5.7.24
Apache Server
```

Error:

```
Notice in .\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#1190
 Undefined offset: 15

Backtrace

.\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#1330: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getTableHeadersForColumns(
array,
array,
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
string 'SELECT * FROM `golfers` ',
)
.\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#4283: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getTableHeaders(
array,
array,
string 'SELECT * FROM `golfers` ',
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#1759: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTable(
,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#2056: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
array,
boolean true,
integer 12,
integer 12,
NULL,
,
array,
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#2281: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(
,
array,
string 'buddies_trip',
string 'golfers',
NULL,
NULL,
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
integer 12,
integer 12,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `golfers` ORDER BY `arrive_depart_AP` ASC ',
NULL,
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#2137: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'buddies_trip',
string 'golfers',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `golfers` ORDER BY `arrive_depart_AP` ASC ',
NULL,
NULL,
)
.\sql.php#220: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'buddies_trip',
string 'golfers',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `golfers`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Comment: What version of PHPmyAdmin have you got? Have you tried updating?

Comment: I’m not sure how to tell. I researched this problem and I was so Confused on what I was reading. It made it sound Like phpmyadmin was a separate program, rather than just up on my browser window through local host. That’s where I’m confused. I can’t find the version anywhere either. I checked MAMP and by clicking the settings wheel in phpmyadmin

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a separate program. It is a tool used to manage your databases. When you open that application on the first page it should tell you which version you have installed. My guess is that you have some old version installed which has some bugs. Try to update it.

Comment: Okay I am downloading it now. The only way I knew how to get to it was through MAMP.